# How can I make a fake name when I use command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a mini game but I want it so that when you press a button over a command block it will say "BOB welcome", so 'bob' instead of the @a or @p sign and then followed by the message.
All I know is that I need to use `/tellraw`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, don't use `/tellraw`, this prints out the raw product rather than running the command inside the quote. If you use `/say` or `/tell` then type something like, "welcome @p to my secret lair" it will come out as, "welcome [name of nearest player] to my secret lair". Command is below:

```
/tell @p "hello there @p, welcome to my lair"
```

Comment: I want it to be like when use use the chat it says your name then the message I want to make it say names so I can add fake people with fake names

Comment: @kingbluesapphire use, /tell @a "@p says' "[blah blah blah]"". this should tell all the players on the server that "[name of nearest player] says,"[blah blah blah]"", sadly you cant specify exaticly who will say it unless you use scoreboard objectives and stuff, it will only be the closest player to the command block.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to rename the Command Block in an Anvil so it says [your imanginary character] in the Name. Then, just use /say on the renamed Command Block and it should do what you asked.

Answer (score -1):

Found this somewhere on the web

```
/tellraw @a {text:"Notch joined the game",color:yellow}

/tellraw @a {text:"Notch left the game",color:yellow}
```

Put each command in a separate command block and you can make people think Notch joined their server. You can copy and paste with Ctrl + C/V on Windows and Command + C/V on Mac (C = Copy, V = Paste.)

Comment: Does this really answer the question?