# Talking in chat from other player's perspectives

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been playing Minecraft 1.12.2 Java Edition on PC. One of my friends started to make me say stuff I wasn't saying in the chat. I don't know what command he was using but he basically made the chat say, "I am an idiot" from **my perspective** (which I never did) and I really want to know how to do it so I can make a comeback and troll him and other people the same way. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Could be something like this: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/sudo.13730/ (also comes with Essentials)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not behaviour you should seek to mimic, though. It's juvenile and deceptive, and could lead to unnecessary arguments. You can just expose the behaviour, and leave it at that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a fake name when I use command blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172231/how-can-i-make-a-fake-name-when-i-use-command-blocks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

he is for sure using a tellraw command. To use it properly advanced knowledge of MC-Commands and/or JSON is helpful, because the tellraw command requires it. I am working with a lot of tellraw commands, so i would recommend using online tellraw-editor. Google is your friend for that.

Use this to to replicate what your friend did:

> /tellraw @a {"text":"< insertNamehere > I'm an idiot!"}

Extra Fake Player-Join-Message, maybe to get some laughs back :D

> /tellraw @a {"color":"yellow","text":"Notch has joined the game"}

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped and I found a good website (minecraftjson.com) that helped. I can't wait for school and now I can troll my friends :D

Answer (score 3):

He probably used [`/tellraw`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tellraw) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/tellraw&oldid=1493676)) and just imitated the name tag at the beginning of the line. You can only do that if you have permission to use commands.

Comment: I did have commands actually...but I don't really know how to use the /tellraw command. I've researched a little and messed around with it but can't get it to work. Could you either explain to me how it works or link any post that explains it?

Comment: The Minecraft wiki, as always: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/tellraw

Comment: There's a problem: I'M IN SCHOOL :(

Comment: I can search it on my phone though...the school laptop literally blocks everything

Comment: I have looked, I have tried, and I DON'T GET IT. STILL. DON'T. GET. IT. Is it because I'm dumb or what? I don't know but I just CAN'T!